# Серветка чи салфетка?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, запозичені-слова

В СУМі є обидва варіанти:

[Салфетка](http://sum.in.ua/s/salfetka), и, жін. Те саме, що серветка.

[Серветка](http://sum.in.ua/s/servetka) - невеликий (звичайно квадратний) шматок тканини або спеціального паперу, який використовують під час їжі, щоб запобігти забрудненню одягу, а також для витирання рук і губів.

[Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) перекладає російське слово "салфетка" як "серветка" або "рушничок". Однак, на Вікіпедії також присутні обидва варіанти. Більше того - жодний з них не є українським, бо "салфетка" - запозичення з російської, а "серветка" - з польської.

То якому ж варіанту кращи надати перевагу? Чи можна вживати обидва варіанти (а судячи з того, що вони є в СУМі без ніяких приміток, то, напевно, відповідь "так")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Як Ви самі зазначили у питанні обидва слова є в СУМ-11 та не мають жодних позначок для обмеження вживання такуж інформація є в ВТССУМ

> [Серветка](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53409/983021.html) -и, ж. 1》 Невеликий (звичайно квадратний) шматок тканини
>   або спеціального паперу, що його використовують під час їжі, щоб
>   запобігти забрудненню одягу, а також для витирання рук і губів.
>
> [Салфетка](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53409/980179.html) -и, ж. Те саме, що серветка.

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B20) містить обидва слова.

> **СЕРВЕ́ТКА, САЛФЕ́ТКА.** *Шеф саме скінчив снідати і витирав серветкою
>   уста (Ірина Вільде); Черговий по столу зібрав посуд, суворовці
>   поскручували салфетки і повкладали їх у кільця (І. Багмут).*

Тому, на мою думку, обидва слова можна сміливо вживати як синоніми та взаємозамінні.